# grep on a variable

Tags: shell, grep, string

Let's say I have a variable

```
line="This is where we select from a table."
```

now I want to grep how many times does select occur in the sentence.

```
grep -ci "select" $line
```

I tried that, but it did not work. I also tried

```
grep -ci "select" "$line"
```

It still doesn't work.  I get the following error.

```
grep: This is where we select from a table.: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to use herestring `...<<<"$line"`  . The command `grep` is expecting a file instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106526/how-can-i-grep-complex-strings-in-variables

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Have `grep` read on its standard input. There you go, using [a pipe](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0060.php)...

```
$ echo "$line" | grep select
```

... or [a here string](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html)...

```
$ grep select <<< "$line"
```

Also, you might want to replace spaces by newlines before grepping :

```
$ echo "$line" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep select
```

... or you could ask `grep` to print the match only:

```
$ echo "$line" | grep -o select
```

This will allow you to get rid of the rest of the line when there's a match.

*Edit:* Oops, read a little too fast, thanks [Marco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12779/marco). In order to count the occurences, just pipe any of these to [`wc(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) ;)

*Another edit made after [lzkata](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12380/izkata)'s comment, quoting `$line` when using `echo`.*

Comment: Since the OP wants to count the number of occurrences of a string you can add a `wc` to complete the task: `grep -o <string> <<< "$variable" | wc -l`

Comment: Use `echo "$line"` to preserve existing newlines instead of creating ones with `tr`

Comment: What is the availability of a Here String? Does it require Bash or another shell?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings), here strings are available in bash, ksh, and zsh (but I'm assuming there may be others).

Comment: i don't understand how bash question indexing is so bad, answers do not answer the question, how to do:

myoutput | grep -v $SOMEVAR 

condition itself is a variable.

Comment: @Aubergine: copy-pastable examples - Filter-string is a variable: `seq 4 | grep -v $SHLVL` ; Filter-string from a different process: `seq 4 | grep -v "$(seq 2)"` Or `seq 4 | grep -vf <(seq 2)` ; Input from a different process: `grep -v $SHLVL <(seq 4)` Or `grep -v $SHLVL <<< "$(seq 4)"`

Answer (score 10):

```
test=$line i=0
while case "$test" in (*select*)
test=${test#*select};;(*) ! :;;
esac; do i=$(($i+1)); done
```

You don't need to call `grep` for such a simple thing.

Or as a function:

```
occur() while case "$1" in (*"$2"*) set -- \
        "${1#*"$2"}" "$2" "${3:-0}" "$((${4:-0}+1))";;
        (*) return "$((${4:-0}<${3:-1}))";;esac
        do : "${_occur:+$((_occur=$4))}";done
```

It takes 2 or 3 args. Providing any more than that will skew its results. You can use it like:

```
_occur=0; occur ... . 2 && echo "count: $_occur"
```

...which prints the occurrence count of `.` in `...` if it occurs at least 2 times. Like this:

```
count: 3
```

If `$_occur` is either empty or `unset` when it is invoked then it will affect no shell variables at all and `return` 1 if `"$2"` occurs in `"$1"` fewer than `"$3"` times. Or, if called with only two args, it will `return` 1 only if `"$2"` is not in `"$1"`. Else it returns 0.

And so, in its simplest form, you can do:

```
occur '' . && echo yay || echo shite
```

...which prints...

```
shite
```

...but...

```
occur . . && echo yay || echo shite
```

...will print...

```
yay
```

You might also write it a little differently and omit the quotes around `$2` in both the `(*"$2"*)` and `"${1#*"$2"}"` statement. If you do that then you can use shell globs for matches like `sh[io]te` for the match test.

Comment: +1: Faster, indeed. Works in `bash` and `dash`/`sh` (and probably a few others).

Comment: @JohnWHSmith - the edit is better, but still just as portable.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use sed to break up the sentence for me and then compare each line in a loop because this seems like the easiest way to me (no offence to anyone here, and also I am not an expert so there may be a reason people don't do it this way, not sure)

```
string="a a a a a asd gsam en"
count=$(echo $string | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep -w 'a' | wc -l)
echo $count
```

when I run it

```
mark@gamerblock:~$ string="a a a a a asd gsam en"
mark@gamerblock:~$ count=$(echo $string | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep -w 'a' | wc -l)
mark@gamerblock:~$ echo $count
5
```

As a script with input argument

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your string"
read string
echo "Enter what you want substring counted"
read substring
count=$(echo $string | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep $substring | wc -l)
echo $count
```

when ran

```
mark@gamerblock:~$ ./substring.sh
Enter your string
peter piper picked a pack of pickled peppers. a pack of pickled peppers peter piper did pick.
Enter what you want substring counted
peter
2
mark@gamerblock:~$ ./substring.sh
Enter your string
peter piper picked a pack of pickled peppers. a pack of pickled peppers peter piper did pick.
Enter what you want substring counted
p
0
```

If you don't want exact matches, remove the -w argument from grep

```
mark@gamerblock:~$ ./substring.sh
Enter your string
peter piper picked a pack of pickled peppers. a pack of pickled peppers peter piper did pick.
Enter what you want substring counted
p
12
mark@gamerblock:~$
```

Comment: This looks a lot like [John WH Smith’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163814/80216). OK, you’ve added ```grep -w```, but you haven’t explained what that does.

Comment: The difference between my answer an Mr. Smith's is that the OP asked for how many matches in a sentence/string, and, to the best of my knowledge, the method using grep (as the OP requested) does not break the sentence into individual lines so that grep can go through it (which is why I used sed). Then wc -l was added to count the number of lines after the regex "select" was matched. The -w on grep makes it only match whole-word results, so something like "selection" won't trigger the filter

Comment: Sorry, upon re-reading, I didn't see the 'tr' command with grep initially. So the only difference in my answer and Mr. Smith's is the use of sed

Comment: There's too many 'e's in argument (twice)

Comment: Fixed, thanks Greenonline!