# grep with variable in a variable

Tags: shell, grep, quoting

I want to filter the svlog file by date and  split the result by the space, 
so when i enter the date,  it didn't work for me,
please refer to the script that I wrote below, the problem was in this command:

```
ligne=`cat /var/log/svlog | grep  "\$day"`
```

, it doesn't consider "\$day". i also tried this "^\$day", this  "$day" and this "${day}" but the same result.

```
#!/bin/bash                 

echo SCRIPT-LOG             
echo enter date         
read day                   

ligne=`cat /var/log/svlog | grep  "\$day"`

$ligne >> log1.txt          

awk '{split($ligne,numbers," ")} END {for(n in numbers){ print numbers[n] }}'>lo


"Monit_Sub.sh" 11 lines, 211 characters

$ sudo ./Monit_Sub.sh 
SCRIPT-LOG
enter date
Apr 26
./Monit_Sub.sh: line 8: Apr: command not found

$
```

Comment: just to correct ligne=` cat /var/log/svlog | grep  "\$day"  ` with this quotes (`)

Comment: This line "$ligne >> log1.txt" is missing an `echo` so your script is trying to execute a command called Apr.  That's the specific error you've got, I've not considered anything else in your script.

Comment: The problem is not on that line "$ligne >> log1.txt", i have omitted  it . but the "ligne" variable is empty there is no result.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are actually trying to do. You are showing your attempt but we have no way of knowing what your actual objective is. For example, is `$ligne >> log1.txt` supposed to execute the command stored in `$ligne` and append its output into `log1.txt` (that's what it does) or was it supposed to append the contents of the variable `$ligne` to the file? Your `awk` command has no input, what is that supposed to do? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Please provide a sample data file and the desired output _using that file_. You should [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Start using `$(this syntax)` for command substitution instead of backticks; the quoting is MUCH easier.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163810/grep-on-a-variable

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
ligne=`cat /var/log/svlog | grep  "\$day"`
```

to

```
ligne=$(grep "$day" /var/log/svlog)
```

To feed the contents of `$ligne` to `awk`, use

```
echo "$ligne" | awk ...
```

Comment: Why would you `echo` that? Just `grep "$day" /var/log/svlog >> log1.txt` is enough.

Comment: @terdon I put in an `echo` because it's not entirely clear to me what OP intended to do with `$ligne`; see @EightBitTony 's comment above

Comment: i dont want echo it. i want to use the result of awk '{split($ligne,numbers," ")} END {for(n in numbers){ print numbers[n] }}'>lo

Comment: @LinuxUser I see. Updated my answer.

Comment: I dont want to echo the variable ligne, i have ommitted this line "$ligne >> log1.txt" . I want to split 
the result of the variable "ligne", but there is no result.

Comment: To process the contents of `$ligne` with awk, you will need to `echo` it into a pipe to awk, see answer.

Comment: It works for me now, is the missing echo on the last line
echo $ligne | awk '{split($0,numbers," ")} END {for(n in numbers){ print numbers[n] }}'